# nodejs issues connecting via ssh2 & public key

Tags: node.js, ssh

I'm trying to connect to a server using ssh2 in a nodeapp.  i was given a host, port, username, and public key.  but i don't see the connect() method having a public key parameter, only a private key parameter.

Any thoughts on how this is supposed to work? Is there another parameter that I'm supposed to use the public key in?  The error I'm getting is "this is not a valid private key"

```
.connect({
  host: host,
  port: 22
  username: un,
  privateKey: key.pub
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass in a public key to connect. The ssh server should have your public key (in an authorized_keys file?).

Just like when you use `ssh` from a terminal and specify a key; you only specify the private key, not the public key.

You're getting an error, because you're trying to pass a public key into the `privateKey` parameter. You should pass in a private key instead.

Comment: You're right.  We had a private key as well and that worked.  Not sure what the public keys they gave us were for.

Comment: @user3527354 The public and private key are part of a single key pair. They require each other to be useful. In this case the server has the public key and you have the private key. Typically you would generate your own key pair, and give the server admin your public key, but keep the private key for yourself; that way you're the only one who has ever had access to your private key, so you can be sure that your encrypted traffic can't be read by anyone else.

Comment: @user3527354 In your case someone generate the key pair for you and sent it to you, so they also may have a copy of your private key and be able to read your encrypted ssh traffic. They gave you both halves of the key, because if you had generated it yourself you would have both halves. If you want access to another server using the same private key, you would need to give that server's administrator your public key.

Comment: what should you you use for the username?

Comment: @LaurenBuxton The username of the user that you are logging in as on the remote server